# Compressing array values into another array

Tags: java, arrays

I came across this problem called compress. The objective is to take an array, remove any repeated values and return a new array.

I know this would be very easy with `ArrayList`s, but I want to do it without them.

So far, I've just written a loop to determine the number of unique values so I can construct a new array of the appropriate length. How can I then get the unique values into the new array?

```
public static int[] compress(int[] array){
    int length = 0;
    boolean contains = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        contains = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (a[i] == a[j]){
                contains = true;
                j = i;
            } else {
                contains = false;
             }
        }
        if (!contains){
            length++;
        }
    }

    int[] uniqueArray = new int[length];        
}
```

Comment: Create a new array of equal length of the original, copy only one value from the original to the new array (so there are no duplicates), keep track of the last location a value was added. Use `Arrays.copyOf` to copy all the unique values (this is why you needed that "last location" value) to an array which meets it's new size

Comment: Think in the way of doing counting sort: define an array whose size is (max - min + 1); iterate through your input array and put count into the counter array; iterate through the counter array and pick indices whose value is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not Tested but I think this should do the trick.

```
    public static int[] copyArray(int [] num){
    int x = 0;
    int numDuplicate = 0;
    int[] copy = new int[num.length]; // we use this to copy the non duplicates
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>(); //hashmap to check duplicates
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        if(count.containsKey(num[i])){
            count.put(num[i], count.get(num[i])+1);
            numDuplicate++; // keep track of duplicates
        }else{
            count.put(num[i], 1); // first occurence
            copy[x] = num[i]; // copy unique values, empty values will be at end
            x++;
        }
    }
    // return only what is needed
    int newSize = num.length - numDuplicate;
    int[] copyNum = new int[newSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < copyNum.length; i++){
        copyNum[i] = copy[i];
    }
    return copyNum;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // sample elements
    int[] nums = new int[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        nums[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copyArray(nums)));

}
```